# Changing words via bitshifting

Tags: assembly, arm

I'll be honest, this is a homework exercise that I am stuck on, and need guidance with.

The task is to change

1) COPE --> HOPE
2) HOPE --> HOPS.

I've managed to do 1) by adding 5 to the bit, which is easy since adding would change the first bit. However, I'm stuck as how to change HOPE To HOPS (2) as now I have to manipulate the last bit.

I was thinking of using `ror`, but if I understand correctly, the ARM assembly language cuts off the bit when it rotates. (Stores only 31 bits instead of 32) So using `ror` changes `HOPE` to `OPEH` for some reason.

Can anyone provide guidance on how to do this?

My code so far:

```
.syntax unified
.global main

main:
    mov R1, #0

@ load "COPE" into r1
cope:
    .ascii "COPE"

ldr r1, cope
mov r2, r1
add r2, #5 ; Got HOPE from COPE now.
mov r3, r2
# Now im stuck
```

Thank you!

Comment: What stops you from adding `0x12000000`?

Comment: It's not bits, but bytes, you are manipulating. In ASCII encoding every letter is using exactly one byte (8 bits). You load the "string" into 32 bit register, 32/8 = 4 => 4 letters will fit (longer string would not). If you will check value of `r2` in hexadecimal formatting, each pair of digits is one byte. I just thought ARM is big-endian, so I would expect `'C'` (`0x43`) in the most-significant-byte (MSB), ie. your `add r2,#5` would affect `'E'`, not `'C'` ... but maybe your ARM is little endian as x86, then `'C'` is least-significant-byte (LSB) and adding 5 will modify it.

Comment: And `ror` does rotate all 32 bits round and round, nothing is lost. So rotating by 8/24 bits will move each letter by 1 position to either direction, the one going over the end-edge will get back into first position. (`'H' (out) <- 'OPE' <- 'H' (in)`).

Comment: @Jester A lack of intelligence i suppose haha. Trying that gave me HOPW instead. How does this work? :)

Comment: @Ped7g Yes the ARM is little endian. However, it seems to store it as 31 bits instead of 32, and chops off the last bit i think?

Comment: @Wboy certainly not. Can you demonstrate on some values and instructions, why do you think so?

Comment: Well if that gives `HOPW` it means I miscalculated the offset. Surely you can fix that ;)

Comment: Is bitshifting a requirement of just a suggestion?

Comment: @InfinitelyManic it was a suggestion :)

Comment: @Jester I understand it now! thank you so much! :) I'd be happy to accept your answer

Comment: @Ped7g it was something my instructor said. I cannot exactly remember the details, but it was something related to using ror would chop off the most significant bit

Comment: @Wboy unfortunately when talking about Assembly instructions every tiny detail does matter. `ror` works over 32 bits for sure, just try to do 32 times `ror` by single position, and step over that piece of code in debugger, watching how the value in register "rotates" back into it's original place. Overall, whenever in doubt, check always the official CPU manufacturer documentation to see instruction description, what it truly does (I mean the fineprint under "rotates register" showing also side-effects and inner details), and then use debugger to verify it works as you understand it.

Answer (score 0):

One idea using EOR (XOR)...

This code example is not intended to be elegant nor efficient and is likely trivial.

```
.data
        array:  .ascii          "COPE"
        .equ    len.array,.-array
        .align
...
_start:
        mov r8, #0x48           // H
        mov r9, #0x53           // S
        mov r10, #len.array     // length of array
        mov r11,#1              // 
        sub r10, r10, r11       // decrement length by 1 since array element begins at 0

        ldr r1,=array           // COPE
        ldrb r2, [r1]           // get first byte size character
        eor r3, r2, r8          // XOR C H -> key
        eor r3, r3, r2          // XOR key C -> H
        strb r3, [r1]           // HOPE

        ldrb r2, [r1,r10]       // get last byte size character
        eor r3, r2, r9          // XOR E S -> key
        eor r3, r3, r2          // XOR key E -> H
        strb r3, [r1,r10]       // HOPS
```

...

gdb results upon stepping...

```
0x200c0:        "COPEA\023"
0x200c0:        "COPEA\023"
0x200c0:        "COPEA\023"
0x200c0:        "COPEA\023"
0x200c0:        "HOPEA\023"
0x200c0:        "HOPEA\023"
0x200c0:        "HOPEA\023"
0x200c0:        "HOPEA\023"
0x200c0:        "HOPEA\023"
0x200c0:        "HOPSA\023"
```